# How to Set the Number of Threads on PyTorch Hosted on AWS Lambda

Tags: multithreading, docker, aws-lambda, pytorch

I'm trying to set the number of threads via `torch.set_num_threads(multiprocessing.cpu_count())` to speed up inference on AWS Lambda. However, it gives me the following stack trace.

```
2022-03-28T16:48:11.625-07:00   Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse the list of possible processors in /sys/devices/system/cpu/possible   2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:11.625-07:00   Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse the list of present processors in /sys/devices/system/cpu/present 2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:11.625-07:00   Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse both lists of possible and present processors 2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:11.801-07:00   /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension:   2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:11.801-07:00   warn(f"Failed to load image Python extension: {e}") 2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00

Copy
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::Error'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::Error' 2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00   what(): [enforce fail at ThreadPool.cc:44] cpuinfo_initialize(). cpuinfo initialization failed  2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00   frame #0: c10::ThrowEnforceNotMet(char const*, int, char const*, std::string const&, void const*) + 0x50 (0x7faf9dc2a0 in /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)    2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00

Copy
frame #1: c10::ThrowEnforceNotMet(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, void const*) + 0x50 (0x7faf9dc440 in /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: c10::ThrowEnforceNotMet(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, void const*) + 0x50 (0x7faf9dc440 in /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)   2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00   frame #2: <unknown function> + 0x1d6cb7c (0x7fb17abb7c in /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)  2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00   frame #3: <unknown function> + 0x1d6fa34 (0x7fb17aea34 in /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)  2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00   frame #4: at::set_num_threads(int) + 0x2c (0x7fb02d082c in /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so) 2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00   frame #5: <unknown function> + 0x498864 (0x7fb52ff864 in /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)    2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00   <omitting python frames>    2022/03/28/[$LATEST]5935023a5e514dbd8cc15036a23cedfe

2022-03-28T16:48:14.200-07:00   Fatal Python error: Aborted
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? For context, I'm deploying a docker image that runs the PyTorch model but the one line I linked above results in this error.

I expected that the program would speed up. Instead, it crashed without a helpful stack trace.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/sys/devices/system/cpu/possible` ? Also, can you check if that directory is mounted inside the container?

Comment: It seems that the lambda container doesn't have one. I get `[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/devices/system/cpu/possible'`. The lambda is using ARM_64 as its architecture. How do you mount the sys directory in the container?

Comment: This may be related to this issue in Pytorch from three years ago: https://github.com/pytorch/cpuinfo/issues/14